# Timestamp tracking

Tags: javascript, triggers, timestamp, no-data, custom-dimensions

I've created a custom timestamp on GA to track the exact moment customers convert. However, it's been over 48 hours and my "timestamp" dimension is not accumulating any data. I have my triggers set to "all pages." I'm wondering if I did something wrong?